# WordPad replacement

Tags: notepad, wordpad

I'm looking for a lite (nothing fancy like notepad++, just simple notepad), open source WordPad replacement. 
It would be great if it could save and open hyperlinks and export files to HTML.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

If open source isn't a necessity, [**Jarte**](http://www.jarte.com/) is a great free Wordpad replacement. It uses Microsoft's Wordpad engine actually.

> Some Features:
>
> - Fully compatible with Windows Vista
> - Tabbed interface to provide easy access to open documents
> - Opens files with file extension RTF, file extension DOC, and file extension
>     DOCX (new default format in Word 2007)
> - Fast start up
> - Compact screen size
> - Hot Connect lets you use Jarte with other programs
> - Optional "Clickless Operation" feature greatly reduces clicking
> - Can be run directly from a pluggable USB flash drive
> - High quality spell checker with custom user dictionary
> - Included spelling dictionaries: English (American, British, &
>     Canadian), Spanish, French, German,
>     Italian, and Dutch
> - Link to, or import, your existing custom Word spelling dictionaries
> - Support for templates
> - **Export to HTML or PDF**
> - Single click bookmarking and bookmark navigation
> - Send documents via e-mail
> - Full drag and drop file support
> - Instant access to recently opened documents and folders
> - Instant access to documents and folders designated as favorites
> - Adjustable document zoom
> - Detailed Help documentation
> - **Insert pictures, hyperlinks, tables, page breaks, equations and other embeddable objects**

It isn't the greatest looking software, but it does the job:

[image]

Comment: The late-nineties called, and they want their user interfaces back!

Answer (score 3):

Notepad++ is probably "lighter" than Wordpad (which isn't even meant for the purpose you're using it for).

I suggest Programmers Notepad, or Eclipse for something more full-featured.

Also; any text editor can "export" to HTML.

Comment: I think by "export to HTML" he is referring to an editor that will retain formatting while exporting to an HTML document for you. For example, if you italicized text it will wrap it in `<i>` tags when saving.

Answer (score 2):

Try Notepad2 if Notepad++ isn't to your liking: http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html